# What happens on Linux (and MacOS) if a process receives a signal while waiting on pthread_cond_wait?

Tags: c, linux, macos, pthreads, signals

In the Linux manual, in the signal(7) manual page, last section of "description", (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) it says that a call to pthread_cond_wait interrupted by a signal will fail with EINTR (unless sa_restart was set in the handler)

Again in the linux manual, in the pthread_cond_wait(3) (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html) page it says:

> These functions shall not return an error code of [EINTR].

Aren't those two pages contradictory?

On my Mac, using the command line manual I can't even find the page signal(7), and the pthread_cond_wait(2) page has no info about failing with EINTR.

I did a test with the following code on MacOS:

```
int main(){
    struct sigaction siga;
    memset(&siga, 0, sizeof(siga));
    siga.sa_handler = handle;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &siga, NULL);
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, task, NULL);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_kill(thread, SIGINT);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    printf("Ended\n");
    return 0;
}

void *task(void * arg){
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    errno = 0;
    int res = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    printf("res = %d\n", res);
    printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
    return 0;
}

void handle(int arg){
}
```

The output is:

```
res = 0
errno = 260
Ended
```

I have no idea what this output means.
I think 260 is even outside the range of system errors.

So how does this actually works in Linux and MacOS?

Comment: The line in pthread_cond_wait is straight from POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html

Comment: Re "*I think 260 is even outside the range of system errors*", `errno` is meaningless if no error was signaled. And that's assuming `pthread_cond_wait` sets `errno`, which it doesn't. `pthread_cond_wait` *returns* the code of the error.

Comment: Usually, when return value is a successful `0`, you cannot trust `errno`.

Comment: Are you confusing 'signal' with 'pthread_cond_signal'?  The level at which the retry happens can be at different layers.  Ie, the posix function call should not return.  However, the OS may call into the user space posix library.  The manuals are not contradictory.  Ie, signal may create an EINTR in a syscall, but the `pthread_cond_wait()` handles all EINTR errors and never returns them.

Comment: Also, look at [man page sections](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html).  7 is misc.  But signal is '2' which is an OS interface level.  '3' is library calls.  Most people don't pay attention to the section numbers, but they are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aren't those two pages contradictory?

Pretty much, but see below.

As a rule of thumb, you should go with the more specific source over the more general one.  In this case, that means relying on the `pthread_cond_wait()`'s manual page for information about the behavior of that function.  Furthermore, I note that the `pthread_cond_wait` manual page you linked echoes [the POSIX specifications for that function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html), and both of those sources also say:

> If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a condition variable, upon return from the signal handler the thread resumes waiting for the condition variable as if it was not interrupted, or it shall return zero due to spurious wakeup.

You report:

> I did a test with the following code on MacOS [...]
>
> The output is:
>
> ```
> res = 0
> errno = 260
> Ended
> ```
>
> I have no idea what this output means.

It means that when interrupted by a signal, your `pthread_cond_wait()` exercised the option of performing a spurious wakeup, returning 0.  This is not an error *per se*.

> I think 260 is even outside the range of system errors.

It is absolutely irrelevant how the number 260 relates to the range of defined system error numbers.  The value of `errno` conveys useful information only in the immediate wake of a function call returning a failure code, and then only for those functions that are documented to set `errno` on error.  `pthread_cond_wait` is not one of those functions -- instead, it is among those whose return value *is* the error number.

> So how does this actually works in Linux and MacOS?

You should interpret the Linux signal(7) manual page to indicate that **on Linux**, after being interrupted by a signal, `pthread_cond_wait()` will be automatically restarted if the handler was registered with the `SA_RESTART` flag, and otherwise it will return to its caller.  If you like, you can reconcile "fails with the error `EINTR`" with the documented behavior of `pthread_cond_signal()` by taking the former to be an abstract specification, realized as returning 0 in the unusual case of `pthread_cond_wait()`.  Or you can just count signal(7) as wrong in this detail.

As for MacOS, your own experiment has shown `pthread_cond_wait()` returning 0 after being interrupted by a signal.  Under other circumstances, the function might be automatically restarted instead.

Comment: I wanted to specifically use this behavior of pthread_cond_wait that returns when signaled to implement a way for producers on a blocking queue to wake up waiting consumers (when the queue is empty and no more elements will be added). The idea was to send a signal to a consumer with an handler that sets a flag and then test this flag right before and after pthread_cond_wait(queue_is_not_empty, ...). If the test is positive then the consumer function returns a special value to then terminate the thread. But seeing the specification for this is not that clear I guess there has to be a better way

Comment: @Ernaldo, for that, one would ordinarily set the flag (under protection of the mutex associated with the CV) then use a `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake all the waiters.  No need for signals there.

Comment: I feel like there is something I'm missing but I see that I should write a separate question for this. Thank you for your help!